# Implementing AES-128 CBC by passing array as input data

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am working on AES-128/192/256, basically I am getting data from a broker as string, I just need to encrypt that data and I need to verify that.

I already come across these https://github.com/empyreanx/tiny-AES128-C, https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c links.

My code is:

```
static void test_encrypt_cbc(void)
{
    unsigned char input[] = 
"So_letmeknowRuinterested/towork@thiscompany.comElsewilllookother";   
 //64bits

    unsigned char cipher[sizeof input];

    printf("size of in:%lu\n",strlen(input));

    unsigned char key[] = "Gns7AauH3dnaod==";    //16 bits
    unsigned char iv[] = "vhdNaleuTHenaOlL";     //16 bits

    AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(cipher, input, 64, key, iv);

    if(0 == memcmp((char*) cipher, (char*) input, 64))
    {
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAILURE!\n");
    }
}
```

I also printed cipher text after encryption it is printing some undefined character.

I don't know but I am comparing "cipher" with "input", Its FAILURE finally!

Please anyone can tell me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is logical to `cipher` to be different from `input`, isn't?

To check that encryption worked, you should decrypt the encoded message and check that they are equal:

```
static void test_encrypt_cbc(void)
{
    /* 64 bytes, or 512 bits */
    unsigned char input[] = 
"So_letmeknowRuinterested/towork@thiscompany.comElsewilllookother";   

    unsigned char cipher[sizeof input];
    unsigned char output[sizeof input];

    printf("size of in:%lu\n",strlen(input));

    /* 16 bytes or 128 bits */
    unsigned char key[] = "Gns7AauH3dnaod==";    
    unsigned char iv[] = "vhdNaleuTHenaOlL";     

    /* input --> cipher */
    AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(cipher, input, 64, key, iv);

    /* cipher --> output */
    AES128_CBC_decrypt_buffer(output, cipher, 64, key, iv);

    if(0 == memcmp((char*) output, (char*) input, 64))
    {
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        printf("FAILURE!\nInput and output are different:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof input; ++i) 
        {
            printf("%02x - %02x\n", input[i], output[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried with same and output is exactly same as input, 
`input_test:
So_letmeknowRuinterested/towork@thiscompany.comElsewilllookother`
`decode_text:
So_letmeknowRuinterested/towork@thiscompany.comElsewilllookother`

but "memcmp" is FAILURE!. why so??

Comment: Well, the last elements in `input` and `output` will be different: `input[64] == '\0'` and `output[64] = ?` Maybe it is the root of the problem? I updated my answer to compare `input` and `output` char by char.